# Manage asyncio coroutines in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-asyncio, coroutine

I want to manage some coroutines in a dict, while running a main coroutine.
Specifically I want to start endless coroutines, put the handler of them in a dict and cancel them via a dict call again. In my example I want to start 4 Coroutines and they shall cancel one by one again with the coroutine `doomsday`. I'm using Python 3.6.

```
import asyncio
import traceback


async def add_to_handler(node, func):
    func_handler[node] = asyncio.ensure_future(func, loop=loop)
    return

async def test_func1():
    while True:
        print("1 - HeNlO")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def test_func2():
    while True:
        print("2 - TestFunc2")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)


async def test_func3():
    while True:
        print("3 - Tukan")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)


async def test_func4():
    while True:
        print("4 - Do Coro!")
        await asyncio.sleep(4)


async def doomsday():
    # Cancel coroutine every 10 seconds
    print("launch doomsday")
    for i in range(len(func_handler)):
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print("start cancelling with {}".format(i))
        func_handler[str(i + 1)].cancel()
    return

async def main():
    await add_to_handler("1", test_func1)
    await add_to_handler("2", test_func2)
    await add_to_handler("3", test_func3)
    await add_to_handler("4", test_func4)
    await doomsday()
    while True:
        print("z..z..Z..Z...Z")
        print(func_handler)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

func_handler = {}

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("stop loop")
    loop.close()
```

I tried it with the `.call_later`method of AbstractEventLoop instead of an endless while loop, but it still doesn't want to work and it seems, that my coroutines are seen as function, but I don't know why. Where is my fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change this function:

```py
async def add_to_handler(node, func):
    func_handler[node] = asyncio.ensure_future(func(), loop=loop)
    return None
```

pay attention on asyncio.ensure_future(**func()**,loop=loop)

Comment: Sometimes it's the small things that are missing,thanks. I tried to put the while True loop in main in a coroutine as well with `asyncio.ensure_future(main_sleep(),loop=loop)` (to be clear, it is not listed in the dict). But after cancelling the last coroutine in the dict, loop quits itself (in a clear way), but shouldn't my main_sleep() coroutine still pending/running?

Comment: Routine main_sleep() will be terminated automatically if ```loop.run_until_complete(main())``` will finish execution and as ```asyncio.ensure_future(main_sleep(), loop=loop)``` is executing in the async loop it's not blocking your main function from finishing its execution, you can do in the way of how it's now or just to call it as ```await main_sleep()```